# What do we call the size of a RSA key? And other specifications

Tags: cryptography, key, rsa, public

I have several question:

- What do we call the size of a RSA key? The size of the product pq? A 1024 bits RSA key means that the representation of n = pq in binary requires exactly 1024 bits or at least 1024?
- When I generate a key of length, let's say, 1024 bits, what is the size of the other parameters such d and e the private and public exponents?
- How, from a DER or PEM format, do we know the size of the key and how to delimit each parameter?
- What is the "version" and what are its possible values?

Comment: Do you ask about some specific application / implementation of RSA? Some of them may have additional requirements: RPKI https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6485 limits signatures RSA keys to "2048-bit modulus and a public exponent (e) of 65,537."; pgp/gpg, openssl, or some other lib/app may have some limits too.

Comment: I was talking aboit openssl command line tool and crypto.publickey in python but I didnt know it depends on tye implementation. I thought there were a norm or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do we call the size of a RSA key? The size of the product pq? A 1024 bits RSA key means that the representation of n = pq in binary requires exactly 1024 bits or at least 1024?

Exactly 1024 bits. If we use the default network order (i.e. big endian) representation then the first bit of the unsigned number should therefore be `1`. That also means that the modulus is always *one byte more* when encoded in ASN.1 / DER as ASN.1 assumes signed numbers.

> When I generate a key of length, let's say, 1024 bits, what is the size of the other parameters such d and e - the private and public exponents?

`d` is often close to the size of the modulus, and always smaller. But in principle any number of `0` bits can be at the most significant end, so it can in theory be of any size. Smaller values of `d` get less likely though, but don't be surprised if multiple *bytes* are set to zero (and therefore missing in the encoding of the number in e.g. ASN.1 / DER).

`e` in principle has the same properties as `d` but it is usually set to a small value during key pair calculation. This usually means it has value `010001` in hexadecimals, or 65537, the fourth Fermat prime (F4 in OpenSSL). This speeds up encryption and verification public key operations.

> How, from a DER or PEM format, do we know the size of the key and how to delimit each parameter?

You have to read the PKCS#1 standards and ASN.1 specifications for that. Numbers are specified in DER encoded ASN.1 INTEGER values. DER uses big endian number, so that would be:

```
TT (LL LL ...) VV VV ...
```

Now the tag `TT` will be set to the value `02` just means INTEGER.

`LL LL ...` is used to indicate the length. Either it is just a single byte up to `80` which directly specifies the size of the value stored in `VV VV ...` or it is set to `8x LL LL ...` where `x` is the number of *length* bytes that follow. `8x LL LL ...` is then simply an unsigned big endian number indicating the size of `VV VV ...`.

`VV VV ...` is the *signed* big endian value.

So `02 03 01 00 01` is often the public exponent. `02 81 00 YY XX XX ...` is the modulus of 128 bytes preceded by a `00` byte to make it an unsigned two complement number. 128 bytes obviously means a key size of 1024 bits. `YY` is always `80` or higher otherwise the key size would be smaller than 1024 bits.

These parameters are just part of an X509 key or *certificate* specification, which is a larger structure. PEM basically consist of a header line, footer line with base 64 (with limited line size) in between. These base 64 characters are the BER or DER encoding of the certificate containing the public key.

Unfortunately I cannot explain the X509 certificate format here, you'll have to read the specifications (RFC) for that.

> What is the "version" and what are its possible values?

That's usually the X509 *certificate & certificate request* version, which is currently set to 3.

Version could also be pointing to the version of the RSA specification. In that case it's often either v1.5 for the old signature / encryption formats or v2.1 for PSS / OAEP *padding methods*.

Comment: I printed hex.bytes_to_hex(RSA.generate(1024).publickey().exportKey('DER'))
where bytes_to_hex is a function of mine. I recognized the end ...02 03 01 00 01 but it starts with 30:81:9f:30:0d... I counter 162 bytes, if I remove the 5 last one and the two first there is 155 left which is 9b, thereforce, from what I understood it should start by 02:9b:00... Why the size isnt 2 + 128 + 5 ? And why does it start by 30 ? 3 looks like the version but the rfc says that for the public key there is no version

Comment: Paste it [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/)

Comment: Thank you, where can I find documentation describing the 6 first fields which, I think, are part of ASN.1

Comment: ASN.1 is a data description language. It does not itself specify the *contents* of the data. It's probably an X509 SubjectPublicKey which is described in the [X509/PKIX specifications](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.7). Also see Appendix A of that same document, which contains a description of all the data element **using** ASN.1 notation.